# How to use vb.net to run Xpath on an embedded XML file in Excel Add-In?

Tags: xml, vb.net, excel, xpath, vsto

**Setup Environment:**

I'm developing an Excel 2010 Application Level Add-in using vb.net with .NET Framework 4.

**My goal:**

1. During run-time, gain access to an embedded XML File in my project
2. Use XpathNavigator to select specific nodes by name

**This code worked for me in a Console Application:**

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.XPath

        Dim nav As XPathNavigator
        Dim docNav As XPathDocument
        Dim NodeIter As XPathNodeIterator
        Dim strExpression As String

        'xmldata.xml is stored in the bin/Debug directory
        docNav = New XPathDocument("xmldata.xml")

        'Create a navigator to query with XPath.
        nav = docNav.CreateNavigator

        'For matching by Well Name
        strExpression = "/wellList/well/name[../name='GN-ALICE- 158-97-1324H-1']"

        'Select the result
        NodeIter = nav.Select(strExpression)


        Console.WriteLine("Well Name: {0}", NodeIter.Current.Value)

        'Show Results
        Console.ReadLine()
```

**Here's where I stored the file:**

[image: Directory]

The file is in the *bin/Debug* directory

**How can I do the same thing when the XML file is embedded as a Project Resource?**

[image: FilePath]

Would someone be willing to give a suggestion on how to go about doing this?  I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: The path to your XML file should be `string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "xmldata.xml");`

Comment: @SteveJansen Thanks for the suggestion.  `Dim xmlfilepath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "xmldata.xml")` works in my code.  However, this is still referring to the XML file in the directory.  I want to refer to the embedded resource (see picture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To solve my problem, I read XML Data from a stream:**

- Where the code is:

  ```
  'xmldata.xml is stored in the bin/Debug directory
  docNav = New XPathDocument("xmldata.xml")
  ```
- Change it to this:

  ```
  Dim stream As System.IO.StringReader
  stream = New StringReader(My.Resources.xmldata)

  docNav = New XPathDocument(stream)
  ```